# Stop jquery from calling function when a slider is opened a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jquery set up to open a sliding panel, and then initiate a second function to start a slide show within that panel. When I close the panel and open it a second time, it calls the function a second time as well, thus giving me duplicate sliders.

```
      $(function() {   
  $('a.everyday').click(function() {
    $('#everyday').addClass('open').stop().animate({top:'30px'},{queue:false,duration:400});

  // Activates Blinds jquery image slider 
  $(function() { 

    $('.slideshow').blinds();

   });
  });
});
```

So the second time the .click function occurs, I'd like jquery to not initiate the .blinds function.

Answer (score 0):

Oops. Misread needs, here's a better version.

```
$(function(){  
    var opened = 0; 
    $('a.everyday').on('click', function() {
        $('#everyday').addClass('open').stop().animate({top:'30px'},{queue:false,duration:400});
        if(opened < 1){
            $('.slideshow').blinds();
            opened++;
        }

     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading blinds should be in your document.ready and not in every onclick handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slideshow').blinds();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {   
  var show = new MyShow();
    show.initialize();
});


var MyShow = function(){
    this.started = false;
    var that = this;
    this.initialize = function (){
    $('a.everyday').click(function() {
            $('#everyday').addClass('open').stop().animate({top:'30px'},{queue:false,duration:400});
        if(!that.started){
            that.started = true;
            // Activates Blinds jquery image slider
            $(function() {

            $('.slideshow').blinds();

       });
        }else{return;}
  });
}
}
```